# Caliburn.Micro display external UserControl

Tags: wpf, caliburn.micro

I'm trying to create a new WPF application using Caliburn.Micro. I have a View where I'd like to display a UserControl from an external assembly that is not following MVVM.

I tried creating a ContentControl on my View, and in the ViewModel I have a property that returns the type of the external usercontrol.

```
<ContentControl Name="SqlConnectLabel" Content="{Binding}" />
```

and

```
public sql.ConnectLabel SqlConnectLabel
{
  get { return p_oConnectLabel; }
  set
  {
    p_oConnectLabel = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => SqlConnectLabel);
  }
}
```

When I run my application, the ContentControl displays "Cannot find view for [Namespace of external UserControl]."

Is there a way to display an external, non-MVVM UserControl like that on a View?

Comment: Why not just drop the control directly onto the design surface (or just add the XAML for it)? You don't need CM to bind it to a VM. This is of course if you aren't resolving the type at runtime (i.e. you have a ref at design time)

Comment: @Charleh, this did the trick. I don't know why I didn't think to try it... *facepalm*. If you add this as an answer I'll accept it since you responded with the suggestion first. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add it to the design surface or XAML as a standard UserControl (since you don't need CM to bind it all up)

Obviously if you are resolving the view at runtime then a different approach is needed, but otherwise, drag and drop!

Comment: I never even copped your comment, I have thrown an upvote on you by way of apology.

Comment: Haha no probs mate, your +1 was my upvote anyway - consider it settled!

Answer (score 2):

Dropping it on as a normal UserControl would be the safest option. In general if it was not built with a MVVM in mind it will be a pain to bind to (Lack of INPC for instance).

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I'm marking Charleh's as the correct answer just based on timing but I gave yours an upvote as well.